# How are assets loaded in flex / images wont update

Tags: apache-flex, flash

**Problem**:

I build a project with Flash Builder. I copied everything from the "bin-debug" directory to a server (including all images we use which are under /assets).

After I have updated the project, and a few images, i recopy the primary .SWF file (Main.swf) and everything under assets up to the server again.

Unfortunately,  when I run the application, I am clearly running all of the updated code but the images have no updated.

The new SWF was definitely copied up as well as the new images (I can say that with 100% certainty), and additionally, I cleared my Flash Cache, so that's most likely not the problem either.

**Question**:

I think I'm lacking a fundamental understanding of how images are loaded in the application. We are using images in our application with the following syntax:

`<s:BitmapImage " source="@Embed('/assets/images/home/bar copy.png')..`.

So are these images actually being compiled into the .SWF file that is produced ... or would that SWF file actually dependent on those images being present on the server's file system under /assets.

If you can point me to any resources or offer a basis explanation, it would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the application is embedding images, that means they are part of the SWF.  You probably don't need to copy the assets folder to your production server.

I'd try recompiling your project (Use a Flash Builder Clean) and test it locally to make sure things are updated, then move the SWF live and test there.

IF it still doesn't how up, you may be having caching issues, so be sure to force the browser cache to clear.

If it still doesn't show up, I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: OK, playing around now if I can figure it out. Do you know if CSS is embedded into the SWF file as well? <fx:Style source="Main.css"/>

Comment: Yes. the CSS is embedded into the SWF as well.

Comment: OK, i figured out my issue. I thought these files were embedded, but in fact, they were actually not embedded :/ So the issue was that the file server was not setting any cache control on the images ... so although I cleared my browser and flash player cache, it didn't have any effect b/c these were cached at the proxy. So we are either going to set some cache control headers on the image responses OR I might try to have a "version" directory under /assets that we rev every time we build the flash application and set cache control to cache indefinitely.

Comment: Also, just to add, I believe we ARE going to continue to copy the assets directory up to production because we have a mix of embedded and non-embedded images. That way, we don't have to concern ourselves about having the correct images in production at all times depending on whether or not they are embedded, we can just copy all of the images every time, that way everything is accessible if needed.